# EC2-RDS setup using Cloudformation not working

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

Cloudformation script to create Ec2 and RDS using proper vpc-subnets getting created but not able to connect to RDS from Ec2

Setup is created properly though script but I have tried connecting to RDS through EC2 using mysql command but not able to connect though entries in security group are correct.
Same infrastructure when i created manually seems to be working fine.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description:
  Cloudformation template 

Parameters:
  EnvironmentName:
    Description: An environment name that will be prefixed to resource names
    Type: String

  VpcCIDR:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for this VPC
    Type: String
    Default: 10.0.0.0/16

  PublicSubnet1CIDR:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for the public subnet in the first Availability Zone
    Type: String
    Default: 10.0.0.0/24

  PrivateSubnet1CIDR:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for the private subnet in the first Availability Zone
    Type: String
    Default: 10.0.1.0/24


Resources:
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref VpcCIDR
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName

  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName

  InternetGatewayAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
      VpcId: !Ref VPC

  PublicSubnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-1a
      CidrBlock: !Ref PublicSubnet1CIDR
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName} Public Subnet (AZ1)


  PrivateSubnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-1c
      CidrBlock: !Ref PrivateSubnet1CIDR
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName} Private Subnet (AZ1)

  PublicRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties: 
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags: 
        - Key: Name 
          Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName} Public Routes        

  DefaultPublicRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: InternetGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway

  PublicSubnet1RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet1


  NoIngressSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: "no-ingress-sg"
      GroupDescription: "Security group with no ingress rule"
      VpcId: !Ref VPC

  InstanceSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Allow http to client host
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 80
        ToPort: 80
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 22
        ToPort: 22
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      SecurityGroupEgress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 80
        ToPort: 80
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0 

  RDSSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Allow http to client host
      VpcId: !Ref VPC


  RDSSecurityGroupIngress:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupId: !Ref RDSSecurityGroup
      IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: 3306
      ToPort: 3306
      SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref InstanceSecurityGroup

  myDBSubnetGroup: 
    Type: "AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup"
    Properties: 
      DBSubnetGroupDescription: "description"
      SubnetIds: 
        - !Ref PublicSubnet1
        - !Ref PrivateSubnet1

  AndroidappControllerInstace:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties: 
      ImageId : ami-0ac019f4fcb7cb7e6
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      KeyName: ansibleawskey
      SubnetId: 
       Ref : PublicSubnet1
      SecurityGroupIds: [!Ref InstanceSecurityGroup]

  AndroidappRDS:   
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      AllocatedStorage: 20
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-1c
      DBInstanceClass: db.t2.micro
      DBInstanceIdentifier: androidappdbidentifier
      DBName: androidappdatabase
      DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref myDBSubnetGroup      
      DeleteAutomatedBackups: true
      Engine: MySQL
      MasterUsername: uname
      MasterUserPassword: pass  
      VPCSecurityGroups: [!Ref RDSSecurityGroup]

Outputs:
  VPC:
    Description: A reference to the created VPC
    Value: !Ref VPC

  PublicSubnets:
    Description: A list of the public subnets
    Value: !Join [ ",", [ !Ref PublicSubnet1 ]]

  PrivateSubnets:
    Description: A list of the private subnets
    Value: !Join [ ",", [ !Ref PrivateSubnet1]]

  PublicSubnet1:
    Description: A reference to the public subnet in the 1st Availability Zone
    Value: !Ref PublicSubnet1

  PrivateSubnet1:
    Description: A reference to the private subnet in the 1st Availability Zone
    Value: !Ref PrivateSubnet1

  NoIngressSecurityGroup:
    Description: Security group with no ingress rule
    Value: !Ref NoIngressSecurityGroup
```

I Should be able to connect to RDS but i cant connect?

Comment: are you sure?  you are not missing anything like privacy and policy and security group ?

Comment: yes security groups are correct, RDS-sg has entry of inbound open for EC2-sg on 3306 port.

Comment: sorry @HarshManvar you were right...outbound for ec2 was not open properly it was only open for port 80.....Thanks for stressing on it.

Comment: some time also happen RDS is accepting only ip from particular EC2 or from particular host people also forget to change the host acess also.